# How to pass a variable to the footer in Jade using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I have a variable I'd like to display in my footer using jade called *total*.

```
.container
    .footer
        hr(style='margin: 30px 0 10px 0;')
        p #{total} records in this database.

link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/style.css')
script(src='/scripts/bootstrap.min.js')

block footer
```

However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to pass that in using Node.

I get passing a variable to a page using...

```
exports.index = function (req, res) {
    "use strict";
    res.render('index', { title: 'My Title' });
};
```

But I'm not understanding how I can do this for the footer layout.

Would I do something like this...

```
res.render('footer', { total: 147});
```

if so how do I define that route in my app.js file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any variables that you pass into `res.render('index')` should be available to the footer view as well.

```
res.render('index', {title: 'My Title', total: 147});
```

If you want to make a variable available in all views, you can use express locals: http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.locals

```
// Put this where you configure your app
app.locals.total = 147
```